# GNU screen freezes when starting session over SSH, works locally. What's wrong?

Tags: gnu-screen

On an iMac running Snow Leopard I can open a terminal window and start a 'screen' session with no issues. However, if I ssh into the same machine (from elsewhere or locally) and then try to start a 'screen' session, it just hangs. No output at all. It won't respond to Ctrl-d, Ctrl-c etc. and has to be killed via it's PID. A session created in a local terminal can be resumed from a ssh session. Does that help direct suspicion towards any config?

I suspect an issue with one of .bashrc, .profile etc., but don't know which applies in this situation, and haven't made any changes in that area recently. All this is done as the same user.

I'm 99% sure this worked not long ago, but I suppose there is a slim possibility that this scenario hasn't cropped up before for me.

In answer to Gilles questions below:

The environment variables are the same in both cases. Most are blank - only COLUMNS, LINES, HOME, PATH, SHELL and TERM were set.

In the hung state, screen isn't taking any input at all. When it is killed the parent shell receives any keyboard input intended for screen. It consumes no CPU time.

Watching the two screen processes that are started, the lower numbered one is doing the following:

```
$ sudo dtruss -p 1545
SYSCALL(args)        = return
sigreturn(0x7FFF5FBFEE80, 0x1E, 0x7FFF5FBFEE80)      = 0 Err#-2
__pthread_canceled(0x0, 0x0, 0x7FFF5FBFEF38)         = -1 Err#22
setitimer(0x0, 0x7FFF5FBFEF40, 0x7FFF5FBFEF20)       = 0 0
kill(0x60A, 0x0, 0x1)        = 0 0
sigaction(0xE, 0x7FFF5FBFEF10, 0x7FFF5FBFEF50)       = 0 0
setitimer(0x0, 0x7FFF5FBFEF40, 0x7FFF5FBFEF20)       = 0 0
sigprocmask(0x0, 0x0, 0x7FFF5FBFEF4C)        = 0x0 0
sigsuspend(0x0, 0x0, 0x0)        = -1 Err#4
<repeats approx every 10s>
```

The higher numbered one only ever outputs:

```
$ sudo dtruss -p 1546
SYSCALL(args)        = return
```

---

The output of 'dtruss -f -p $pid_of_bash_that_starts_screen' with the duplication removed is:

```
1500/0x15a94:  write_nocancel(0x2, "s\0", 0x1)       = 1 0
1500/0x15a94:  sigprocmask(0x1, 0x0, 0x7FFF5FBFEB00)         = 0x0 0
1500/0x15a94:  sigaltstack(0x0, 0x7FFF5FBFEAF0, 0x0)         = 0 0
1500/0x15a94:  read(0x0, "c\0", 0x1)         = 1 0
1500/0x15a94:  write_nocancel(0x2, "c\0", 0x1)       = 1 0
1500/0x15a94:  sigprocmask(0x1, 0x0, 0x7FFF5FBFEB00)         = 0x0 0
1500/0x15a94:  sigaltstack(0x0, 0x7FFF5FBFEAF0, 0x0)         = 0 0
1500/0x15a94:  read(0x0, "r\0", 0x1)         = 1 0
1500/0x15a94:  write_nocancel(0x2, "r\0", 0x1)       = 1 0
1500/0x15a94:  sigprocmask(0x1, 0x0, 0x7FFF5FBFEB00)         = 0x0 0
1500/0x15a94:  sigaltstack(0x0, 0x7FFF5FBFEAF0, 0x0)         = 0 0
1500/0x15a94:  read(0x0, "e\0", 0x1)         = 1 0
1500/0x15a94:  write_nocancel(0x2, "e\0", 0x1)       = 1 0
1500/0x15a94:  sigprocmask(0x1, 0x0, 0x7FFF5FBFEB00)         = 0x0 0
1500/0x15a94:  sigaltstack(0x0, 0x7FFF5FBFEAF0, 0x0)         = 0 0
1500/0x15a94:  read(0x0, "e\0", 0x1)         = 1 0
1500/0x15a94:  write_nocancel(0x2, "e\0", 0x1)       = 1 0
1500/0x15a94:  sigprocmask(0x1, 0x0, 0x7FFF5FBFEB00)         = 0x0 0
1500/0x15a94:  sigaltstack(0x0, 0x7FFF5FBFEAF0, 0x0)         = 0 0
1500/0x15a94:  read(0x0, "n\0", 0x1)         = 1 0
1500/0x15a94:  write_nocancel(0x2, "n\352\277_\377\177\0", 0x1)      = 1 0
1500/0x15a94:  sigprocmask(0x1, 0x0, 0x7FFF5FBFEB00)         = 0x0 0
1500/0x15a94:  sigaltstack(0x0, 0x7FFF5FBFEAF0, 0x0)         = 0 0
1500/0x15a94:  fork()        = 1635 0
1500/0x15a94:  setpgid(0x663, 0x663, 0x5DD)      = 0 0
1500/0x15a94:  sigprocmask(0x3, 0x7FFF5FBFF9C8, 0x0)         = 0x0 0
1500/0x15a94:  sigprocmask(0x1, 0x7FFF5FBFFA8C, 0x7FFF5FBFFA88)      = 0x0 0
1500/0x15a94:  sigprocmask(0x1, 0x7FFF5FBFFA2C, 0x7FFF5FBFFA28)      = 0x0 0
1500/0x15a94:  ioctl(0xFF, 0x4004667A, 0x7FFF5FBFF97C)       = 0 0
1500/0x15a94:  ioctl(0xFF, 0x80047476, 0x7FFF5FBFF9FC)       = 0 0
1500/0x15a94:  sigprocmask(0x3, 0x7FFF5FBFFA28, 0x0)         = 0x0 0
1500/0x15a94:  sigprocmask(0x3, 0x7FFF5FBFFA88, 0x0)         = 0x0 0
1500/0x15a94:  sigprocmask(0x1, 0x7FFF5FBFFA8C, 0x7FFF5FBFFA88)      = 0x0 0
1635/0x1654c:  ioctl(0x3, 0x80086804, 0x7FFF5FBFD6A0)        = 0 0
1635/0x1654c:  close(0x3)        = 0 0
1635/0x1654c:  __sysctl(0x7FFF5FBFD590, 0x2, 0x7FFF5FBFD580)         = 0 0
1635/0x1654c:  bsdthread_register(0x7FFF82BA42FC, 0x7FFF82B84F18, 0x2000)        = 0 0
1635/0x1654c:  thread_selfid(0x7FFF82BA42FC, 0x7FFF82B84F18, 0x0)        = 91468 0
1635/0x1654c:  open_nocancel("/dev/urandom\0", 0x0, 0x7FFF705D1B60)      = 3 0
1635/0x1654c:  read_nocancel(0x3, "g\307\017\235\330=\212e\272\357o\351\207\365\207\0023Ra^\372\344z8\nf\253\205\335\177v\261\365\241pj\360rNW\333\344\331\300\250W\f\273O&<\232\257\034^\350!\n\351&\231P\\\025\0", 0x40)       = 64 0
1635/0x1654c:  close_nocancel(0x3)       = 0 0
1635/0x1654c:  mmap(0x0, 0x3000, 0x3, 0x1002, 0x1000000, 0x7FFF00000001)         = 0x59000 0
1635/0x1654c:  __sysctl(0x7FFF5FBFD410, 0x2, 0x7FFF5FBFD3D0)         = 0 0
1635/0x1654c:  __sysctl(0x7FFF5FBFD3D0, 0x2, 0x7FFF5FBFD468)         = 0 0
1635/0x1654c:  getpid(0x7FFF5FBFD360, 0x7FFFFFE00050, 0x0)       = 1635 0
1635/0x1654c:  open_nocancel("/dev/urandom\0", 0x0, 0x0)         = 3 0
1635/0x1654c:  read_nocancel(0x3, ":juq\236\223OW\305\231,\002\205\235E\346_\236>H\t\026=\213\220\\\020\tN?\240\254\361\262q<e\300M\252\200le<\241$\027\377\252Xs\034\355\212+#z+\241\033I\346s\017\227\244\351\227\024\272\361\263Qn\315\354U\312\211\017\313\265\f\033I\341\300\372Id\327\251tB\016\026/(\313\214\266\242S\275\351\372Y{\0", 0x6C)         = 108 0
1635/0x1654c:  close_nocancel(0x3)       = 0 0
1635/0x1654c:  __sysctl(0x7FFF5FBFD410, 0x2, 0x7FFF5FBFD43C)         = 0 0
1635/0x1654c:  mmap(0x0, 0xD000, 0x3, 0x1002, 0x1000000, 0x7FFF00000001)         = 0x5C000 0
1635/0x1654c:  mmap(0x0, 0xD000, 0x3, 0x1002, 0x1000000, 0x7FFF00000001)         = 0x69000 0
1635/0x1654c:  mmap(0x0, 0x1000, 0x3, 0x1002, 0x1000000, 0x7FFF00000001)         = 0x76000 0
1635/0x1654c:  mmap(0x0, 0x200000, 0x3, 0x1002, 0x7000000, 0x7FFF00000001)       = 0x77000 0
1635/0x1654c:  munmap(0x100077000, 0x89000)      = 0 0
1635/0x1654c:  munmap(0x100200000, 0x77000)      = 0 0
1635/0x1654c:  __sysctl(0x7FFF5FBFD570, 0x2, 0x7FFF5FBFD530)         = 0 0
1635/0x1654c:  __sysctl(0x7FFF5FBFD530, 0x2, 0x7FFF705DE6C0)         = 0 0
1635/0x1654c:  __sysctl(0x7FFF5FBFD570, 0x2, 0x7FFF5FBFD530)         = 0 0
1635/0x1654c:  __sysctl(0x7FFF5FBFD530, 0x2, 0x7FFF705DE6C4)         = 0 0
1635/0x1654c:  __sysctl(0x7FFF5FBFD570, 0x2, 0x7FFF5FBFD530)         = 0 0
1635/0x1654c:  __sysctl(0x7FFF5FBFD530, 0x2, 0x7FFF705DE6C8)         = 0 0
1635/0x1654c:  getdtablesize(0x0, 0x7FFF5FBFFA40, 0x0)       = 256 0
1635/0x1654c:  close(0xFF)       = -1 Err#9
...
1635/0x1654c:  close(0x3)        = -1 Err#9
1635/0x1654c:  getuid(0x10002D277, 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF, 0x7FFF5FBFF3D1)       = 502 0
1635/0x1654c:  getgid(0x10002D277, 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF, 0x0)      = 20 0
1635/0x1654c:  geteuid(0x10002D277, 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF, 0x0)         = 502 0
1635/0x1654c:  getegid(0x10002D277, 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF, 0x0)         = 20 0
1635/0x1654c:  sigaction(0x19, 0x7FFF5FBFF200, 0x7FFF5FBFF240)       = 0 0
1635/0x1654c:  sigaction(0xD, 0x7FFF5FBFF200, 0x7FFF5FBFF240)        = 0 0
1635/0x1654c:  access("/Users/chris/.nethackrc\0", 0x0, 0x17)        = -1 Err#2
1635/0x1654c:  getlogin(0x7FFF705D05A0, 0xFF, 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF)        = 0 0
1635/0x1654c:  mmap(0x0, 0x1000000, 0x3, 0x1002, 0x2000000, 0x100000000)         = 0x200000 0
1635/0x1654c:  munmap(0x100200000, 0x600000)         = 0 0
1635/0x1654c:  munmap(0x101000000, 0x200000)         = 0 0
1635/0x1654c:  shm_open(0x7FFF82CBF980, 0x0, 0x0)        = 3 0
1635/0x1654c:  mmap(0x0, 0x1000, 0x1, 0x1, 0x3, 0x100000000)         = 0x77000 0
1635/0x1654c:  close_nocancel(0x3)       = 0 0
1635/0x1654c:  getrlimit(0x1008, 0x7FFF5FBFEFF0, 0x7FFF82B6E86C)         = 0 0
1635/0x1654c:  open_nocancel("/etc/sysinfo.conf\0", 0x0, 0x1B6)      = -1 Err#2
1635/0x1654c:  stat64("/var/folders/jJ/jJ6dXorgFwuvL9p+qVUNVU+++TM/\0", 0x7FFF5FBFED00, 0x0)         = 0 0
1635/0x1654c:  mkdir("/var/folders/jJ/jJ6dXorgFwuvL9p+qVUNVU+++TM/-Tmp-/\0", 0x1C0, 0x7FFF5FBFEE13)      = -1 Err#17
1635/0x1654c:  access("/var/folders/jJ/jJ6dXorgFwuvL9p+qVUNVU+++TM/-Tmp-/.screen\0", 0x0, 0x3C0)         = 0 0
1635/0x1654c:  stat64("/var/folders/jJ/jJ6dXorgFwuvL9p+qVUNVU+++TM/-Tmp-/.screen\0", 0x7FFF5FBFF2C0, 0x0)        = 0 0
1635/0x1654c:  umask(0x12, 0x7FFF5FBFF2C0, 0x80808000)       = 0 0
1635/0x1654c:  __sysctl(0x7FFF5FBFF110, 0x2, 0x7FFF5FBFF120)         = 0 0
1635/0x1654c:  sigaction(0x1, 0x7FFF5FBFF200, 0x7FFF5FBFF240)        = 0 0
1635/0x1654c:  fork()        = 1636 0
1635/0x1654c:  setgid(0x14, 0x7FFF5FBFF7F1, 0x10005364B)         = 0 0
1635/0x1654c:  setuid(0x1F6, 0x7FFF5FBFF7F1, 0x0)        = 0 0
1635/0x1654c:  sigaction(0x1, 0x7FFF5FBFEF10, 0x7FFF5FBFEF50)        = 0 0
1635/0x1654c:  sigaction(0x1, 0x7FFF5FBFEF10, 0x7FFF5FBFEF50)        = 0 0
1635/0x1654c:  sigaction(0x1E, 0x7FFF5FBFEF10, 0x7FFF5FBFEF50)       = 0 0
1635/0x1654c:  sigaction(0x1F, 0x7FFF5FBFEF10, 0x7FFF5FBFEF50)       = 0 0
1635/0x1654c:  sigaction(0x2, 0x7FFF5FBFEF10, 0x7FFF5FBFEF50)        = 0 0
1635/0x1654c:  sigaction(0x12, 0x7FFF5FBFEF10, 0x7FFF5FBFEF50)       = 0 0
1635/0x1654c:  sigaction(0x1C, 0x7FFF5FBFEF10, 0x7FFF5FBFEF50)       = 0 0
1635/0x1654c:  sigaction(0xE, 0x7FFF5FBFEF10, 0x7FFF5FBFEF50)        = 0 0
1635/0x1654c:  setitimer(0x0, 0x7FFF5FBFEF40, 0x7FFF5FBFEF20)        = 0 0
1635/0x1654c:  sigprocmask(0x0, 0x0, 0x7FFF5FBFEF4C)         = 0x0 0
1636/0x1654e:  fstat64(0x2, 0x7FFF5FBFE5F0, 0x7FFF5FBFE6BC)      = 0 0
1636/0x1654e:  ioctl(0x2, 0x4004667A, 0x7FFF5FBFE63C)        = 0 0
1636/0x1654e:  write_nocancel(0x2, "SCREEN: can't detach from console\n\0", 0x22)        = 34 0
1635/0x1654c:  sigsuspend(0x0, 0x0, 0x0)         = -1 Err#4
1635/0x1654c:  __pthread_canceled(0x0, 0x0, 0x7FFF5FBFEF38)      = -1 Err#22
1635/0x1654c:  setitimer(0x0, 0x7FFF5FBFEF40, 0x7FFF5FBFEF20)        = 0 0
1635/0x1654c:  kill(0x664, 0x0, 0x1)         = 0 0
1635/0x1654c:  sigaction(0xE, 0x7FFF5FBFEF10, 0x7FFF5FBFEF50)        = 0 0
1635/0x1654c:  setitimer(0x0, 0x7FFF5FBFEF40, 0x7FFF5FBFEF20)        = 0 0
1635/0x1654c:  sigprocmask(0x0, 0x0, 0x7FFF5FBFEF4C)         = 0x0 0
1500/0x15a94:  read(0x0, "\r\006\0", 0x1)        = 1 0
1500/0x15a94:  write_nocancel(0x2, "\n\006\0", 0x1)      = 1 0
1500/0x15a94:  sigprocmask(0x1, 0x1000A5984, 0x1000A5988)        = 0x0 0
1500/0x15a94:  ioctl(0x0, 0x80487414, 0x1000A59C0)       = 0 0
1500/0x15a94:  sigprocmask(0x3, 0x1000A5988, 0x0)        = 0x0 0
1500/0x15a94:  sigaction(0x2, 0x7FFF5FBFEAE0, 0x7FFF5FBFEB10)        = 0 0
1500/0x15a94:  sigaction(0xF, 0x7FFF5FBFEAE0, 0x7FFF5FBFEB10)        = 0 0
1500/0x15a94:  sigaction(0x3, 0x7FFF5FBFEAE0, 0x7FFF5FBFEB10)        = 0 0
1500/0x15a94:  sigaction(0xE, 0x7FFF5FBFEAE0, 0x7FFF5FBFEB10)        = 0 0
1500/0x15a94:  sigaction(0x12, 0x7FFF5FBFEAE0, 0x7FFF5FBFEB10)       = 0 0
1500/0x15a94:  sigaction(0x16, 0x7FFF5FBFEAE0, 0x7FFF5FBFEB10)       = 0 0
1500/0x15a94:  sigaction(0x15, 0x7FFF5FBFEAE0, 0x7FFF5FBFEB10)       = 0 0
1500/0x15a94:  sigaction(0x1C, 0x7FFF5FBFEAE0, 0x7FFF5FBFEB10)       = 0 0
1500/0x15a94:  sigaction(0x2, 0x7FFF5FBFEB00, 0x7FFF5FBFEB30)        = 0 0
1500/0x15a94:  gettimeofday(0x7FFF5FBFE9D0, 0x0, 0x1F80)         = 1289128377 0
1500/0x15a94:  sigprocmask(0x1, 0x7FFF5FBFF9CC, 0x7FFF5FBFF9C8)      = 0x0 0
1635/0x1654c:  fork()        = 0 0
1635/0x1654c:  thread_selfid(0x7FFF705D4C20, 0x3, 0x1)       = 91468 0
1635/0x1654c:  getpid(0x7FFF705D4C20, 0x3, 0x0)      = 1635 0
1635/0x1654c:  sigprocmask(0x3, 0x1000A69D8, 0x0)        = 0x0 0
1635/0x1654c:  sigaction(0x12, 0x7FFF5FBFF950, 0x7FFF5FBFF980)       = 0 0
1635/0x1654c:  sigaction(0x15, 0x7FFF5FBFF950, 0x7FFF5FBFF980)       = 0 0
1635/0x1654c:  sigaction(0x16, 0x7FFF5FBFF960, 0x7FFF5FBFF990)       = 0 0
1635/0x1654c:  setpgid(0x663, 0x663, 0x0)        = 0 0
1635/0x1654c:  sigprocmask(0x1, 0x7FFF5FBFF98C, 0x7FFF5FBFF988)      = 0x0 0
1635/0x1654c:  ioctl(0xFF, 0x4004667A, 0x7FFF5FBFF8DC)       = 0 0
1635/0x1654c:  ioctl(0xFF, 0x80047476, 0x7FFF5FBFF95C)       = 0 0
1635/0x1654c:  sigprocmask(0x3, 0x7FFF5FBFF988, 0x0)         = 0x0 0
1635/0x1654c:  sigaction(0x2, 0x7FFF5FBFF950, 0x7FFF5FBFF980)        = 0 0
1635/0x1654c:  sigaction(0x3, 0x7FFF5FBFF950, 0x7FFF5FBFF980)        = 0 0
1635/0x1654c:  sigaction(0xF, 0x7FFF5FBFF950, 0x7FFF5FBFF980)        = 0 0
1635/0x1654c:  sigaction(0x14, 0x7FFF5FBFF950, 0x7FFF5FBFF980)       = 0 0
1635/0x1654c:  execve(0x1001D0C30, 0x1001D0D20, 0x1001CFC40)         = 0 0
1635/0x1654c:  gettimeofday(0x7FFF5FBFF850, 0x0, 0x7FFF5FBFFA50)         = 1289128377 0
1635/0x1654c:  getpid(0x7FFF5FBFF850, 0x0, 0x0)      = 1635 0
1635/0x1654c:  open_nocancel("/dev/urandom\0", 0x0, 0x0)         = 3 0
1635/0x1654c:  read_nocancel(0x3, "\021M\323J\242\363\227\001py\363h\331\321)\326\216\300r\n9r\b\252g\342\326\003\242\340\246\311\0", 0x6C)      = 108 0
1635/0x1654c:  close_nocancel(0x3)       = 0 0
1635/0x1654c:  issetugid(0x100000000, 0x7FFF5FBFFB18, 0x7FFF5FC40530)        = 0 0
1635/0x1654c:  geteuid(0x100000000, 0x7FFF5FBFFB18, 0x0)         = 502 0
1635/0x1654c:  __sysctl(0x7FFF5FBFD740, 0x2, 0x7FFF5FBFD700)         = 0 0
1635/0x1654c:  __sysctl(0x7FFF5FBFD700, 0x2, 0x7FFF5FBFD79C)         = 0 0
1635/0x1654c:  shared_region_check_np(0x7FFF5FBFD908, 0x0, 0x7FFF5FC1DC86)       = 0 0
1635/0x1654c:  stat64("/Applications/ImageMagick/lib/libncurses.5.4.dylib\0", 0x7FFF5FBFCE50, 0x7FFF5FBFD0F0)        = -1 Err#2
1635/0x1654c:  stat64("/usr/lib/libncurses.5.4.dylib\0", 0x7FFF5FBFCAB0, 0x7FFF5FBFD0F0)         = 0 0
1635/0x1654c:  stat64("/Applications/ImageMagick/lib/libSystem.B.dylib\0", 0x7FFF5FBFCE50, 0x7FFF5FBFD0F0)       = -1 Err#2
1635/0x1654c:  stat64("/usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib\0", 0x7FFF5FBFCAB0, 0x7FFF5FBFD0F0)        = 0 0
1635/0x1654c:  stat64("/Applications/ImageMagick/lib/libmathCommon.A.dylib\0", 0x7FFF5FBFCBB0, 0x7FFF5FBFCE50)       = -1 Err#2
1635/0x1654c:  stat64("/usr/lib/system/libmathCommon.A.dylib\0", 0x7FFF5FBFC810, 0x7FFF5FBFCE50)         = 0 0
1635/0x1654c:  madvise(0x7FFF89561000, 0x2000, 0x5)      = 0 0
1635/0x1654c:  open("/dev/dtracehelper\0", 0x2, 0x7FFF5FC451F8)      = 3 0
1635/0x1654c:  ioctl(0x0, 0x40487413, 0x7FFF5FBFF1E0)        = 0 0
1635/0x1654c:  fstat64(0x0, 0x7FFF5FBFF150, 0x0)         = 0 0
1635/0x1654c:  open_nocancel("/dev/\0", 0x100004, 0x0)       = 3 0
1635/0x1654c:  fcntl_nocancel(0x3, 0x2, 0x1)         = 0 0
1635/0x1654c:  __sysctl(0x7FFF5FBFE5E0, 0x2, 0x7FFF705D6698)         = 0 0
1635/0x1654c:  fstatfs64(0x3, 0x7FFF5FBFE630, 0x0)       = 0 0
1635/0x1654c:  getdirentries64(0x3, 0x100801400, 0x1000)         = 3080 0
1635/0x1654c:  lstat64("/dev/.\0", 0x7FFF5FBFEF70, 0x0)      = 0 0
1635/0x1654c:  lstat64("/dev/..\0", 0x7FFF5FBFEF70, 0x0)         = 0 0
1635/0x1654c:  lstat64("/dev/console\0", 0x7FFF5FBFEF70, 0x0)        = 0 0
1635/0x1654c:  lstat64("/dev/tty\0", 0x7FFF5FBFEF70, 0x0)        = 0 0
1635/0x1654c:  lstat64("/dev/null\0", 0x7FFF5FBFEF70, 0x0)       = 0 0
1635/0x1654c:  lstat64("/dev/zero\0", 0x7FFF5FBFEF70, 0x0)       = 0 0
1635/0x1654c:  lstat64("/dev/klog\0", 0x7FFF5FBFEF70, 0x0)       = 0 0
1635/0x1654c:  lstat64("/dev/fd\0", 0x7FFF5FBFEF70, 0x0)         = 0 0
1635/0x1654c:  lstat64("/dev/stdin\0", 0x7FFF5FBFEF70, 0x0)      = 0 0
1635/0x1654c:  lstat64("/dev/stdout\0", 0x7FFF5FBFEF70, 0x0)         = 0 0
1635/0x1654c:  lstat64("/dev/stderr\0", 0x7FFF5FBFEF70, 0x0)         = 0 0
1635/0x1654c:  lstat64("/dev/auditpipe\0", 0x7FFF5FBFEF70, 0x0)      = 0 0
1635/0x1654c:  lstat64("/dev/ttyp0\0", 0x7FFF5FBFEF70, 0x0)      = 0 0
1635/0x1654c:  lstat64("/dev/ptyp0\0", 0x7FFF5FBFEF70, 0x0)      = 0 0
...
1635/0x1654c:  lstat64("/dev/ttywf\0", 0x7FFF5FBFEF70, 0x0)      = 0 0
1635/0x1654c:  lstat64("/dev/ptywf\0", 0x7FFF5FBFEF70, 0x0)      = 0 0
1635/0x1654c:  lstat64("/dev/ptmx\0", 0x7FFF5FBFEF70, 0x0)       = 0 0
1635/0x1654c:  lstat64("/dev/vn0\0", 0x7FFF5FBFEF70, 0x0)        = 0 0
1635/0x1654c:  lstat64("/dev/vn1\0", 0x7FFF5FBFEF70, 0x0)        = 0 0
1635/0x1654c:  lstat64("/dev/vn2\0", 0x7FFF5FBFEF70, 0x0)        = 0 0
1635/0x1654c:  lstat64("/dev/vn3\0", 0x7FFF5FBFEF70, 0x0)        = 0 0
1635/0x1654c:  lstat64("/dev/bpf0\0", 0x7FFF5FBFEF70, 0x0)       = 0 0
1635/0x1654c:  lstat64("/dev/bpf1\0", 0x7FFF5FBFEF70, 0x0)       = 0 0
1635/0x1654c:  lstat64("/dev/bpf2\0", 0x7FFF5FBFEF70, 0x0)       = 0 0
1635/0x1654c:  lstat64("/dev/bpf3\0", 0x7FFF5FBFEF70, 0x0)       = 0 0
1635/0x1654c:  lstat64("/dev/fsevents\0", 0x7FFF5FBFEF70, 0x0)       = 0 0
1635/0x1654c:  lstat64("/dev/random\0", 0x7FFF5FBFEF70, 0x0)         = 0 0
1635/0x1654c:  lstat64("/dev/urandom\0", 0x7FFF5FBFEF70, 0x0)        = 0 0
1635/0x1654c:  lstat64("/dev/dtrace\0", 0x7FFF5FBFEF70, 0x0)         = 0 0
1635/0x1654c:  lstat64("/dev/dtracehelper\0", 0x7FFF5FBFEF70, 0x0)       = 0 0
1635/0x1654c:  lstat64("/dev/lockstat\0", 0x7FFF5FBFEF70, 0x0)       = 0 0
1635/0x1654c:  lstat64("/dev/sdt\0", 0x7FFF5FBFEF70, 0x0)        = 0 0
1635/0x1654c:  lstat64("/dev/systrace\0", 0x7FFF5FBFEF70, 0x0)       = 0 0
1635/0x1654c:  lstat64("/dev/machtrace\0", 0x7FFF5FBFEF70, 0x0)      = 0 0
1635/0x1654c:  lstat64("/dev/fbt\0", 0x7FFF5FBFEF70, 0x0)        = 0 0
1635/0x1654c:  lstat64("/dev/profile\0", 0x7FFF5FBFEF70, 0x0)        = 0 0
1635/0x1654c:  getdirentries64(0x3, 0x100801400, 0x1000)         = 888 0
1635/0x1654c:  lstat64("/dev/pmCPUClient\0", 0x7FFF5FBFEF70, 0x0)        = 0 0
1635/0x1654c:  lstat64("/dev/disk0\0", 0x7FFF5FBFEF70, 0x0)      = 0 0
1635/0x1654c:  lstat64("/dev/rdisk0\0", 0x7FFF5FBFEF70, 0x0)         = 0 0
1635/0x1654c:  lstat64("/dev/disk0s1\0", 0x7FFF5FBFEF70, 0x0)        = 0 0
1635/0x1654c:  lstat64("/dev/rdisk0s1\0", 0x7FFF5FBFEF70, 0x0)       = 0 0
1635/0x1654c:  lstat64("/dev/disk0s2\0", 0x7FFF5FBFEF70, 0x0)        = 0 0
1635/0x1654c:  lstat64("/dev/rdisk0s2\0", 0x7FFF5FBFEF70, 0x0)       = 0 0
1635/0x1654c:  lstat64("/dev/io8log\0", 0x7FFF5FBFEF70, 0x0)         = 0 0
1635/0x1654c:  lstat64("/dev/io8logmt\0", 0x7FFF5FBFEF70, 0x0)       = 0 0
1635/0x1654c:  lstat64("/dev/cu.Bluetooth-Modem\0", 0x7FFF5FBFEF70, 0x0)         = 0 0
1635/0x1654c:  lstat64("/dev/tty.Bluetooth-Modem\0", 0x7FFF5FBFEF70, 0x0)        = 0 0
1635/0x1654c:  lstat64("/dev/cu.W880i-SerialPort\0", 0x7FFF5FBFEF70, 0x0)        = 0 0
1635/0x1654c:  lstat64("/dev/tty.W880i-SerialPort\0", 0x7FFF5FBFEF70, 0x0)       = 0 0
1635/0x1654c:  lstat64("/dev/cu.Bluetooth-PDA-Sync\0", 0x7FFF5FBFEF70, 0x0)      = 0 0
1635/0x1654c:  lstat64("/dev/tty.Bluetooth-PDA-Sync\0", 0x7FFF5FBFEF70, 0x0)         = 0 0
1635/0x1654c:  lstat64("/dev/autofs\0", 0x7FFF5FBFEF70, 0x0)         = 0 0
1635/0x1654c:  lstat64("/dev/autofs_nowait\0", 0x7FFF5FBFEF70, 0x0)      = 0 0
1635/0x1654c:  lstat64("/dev/autofs_control\0", 0x7FFF5FBFEF70, 0x0)         = 0 0
1635/0x1654c:  lstat64("/dev/ttys000\0", 0x7FFF5FBFEF70, 0x0)        = 0 0
1635/0x1654c:  lstat64("/dev/ttys002\0", 0x7FFF5FBFEF70, 0x0)        = 0 0
1635/0x1654c:  close_nocancel(0x3)       = 0 0
1635/0x1654c:  stat64("/dev/ttys002\0", 0x7FFF5FBFF2C0, 0x7FFF705D03A0)      = 0 0
1635/0x1654c:  seteuid(0x1F6, 0x6, 0x0)      = 0 0
1635/0x1654c:  setegid(0x14, 0x6, 0x0)       = 0 0
1635/0x1654c:  open("/dev/ttys002\0", 0x6, 0x0)      = 3 0
1635/0x1654c:  seteuid(0x1F6, 0x6, 0x0)      = 0 0
1635/0x1654c:  setegid(0x14, 0x6, 0x0)       = 0 0
1635/0x1654c:  close(0x3)        = 0 0
1635/0x1654c:  ioctl(0x0, 0x40487413, 0x100053C20)       = 0 0
1635/0x1654c:  umask(0x0, 0x40487413, 0x0)       = 18 0
1635/0x1654c:  geteuid(0x1, 0x7FFF5FBFEDE0, 0x400)       = 502 0
1636/0x1654e:  fork()        = 0 0
1636/0x1654e:  thread_selfid(0x7FFF705D4C20, 0x3, 0x1)       = 91470 0
1636/0x1654e:  getpid(0x7FFF705D4C20, 0x3, 0x0)      = 1636 0
1636/0x1654e:  seteuid(0x1F6, 0x2, 0x0)      = 0 0
1636/0x1654e:  setegid(0x14, 0x2, 0x0)       = 0 0
1636/0x1654e:  open("/dev/ttys002\0", 0x2, 0x0)      = 3 0
1636/0x1654e:  seteuid(0x1F6, 0x2, 0x0)      = 0 0
1636/0x1654e:  setegid(0x14, 0x2, 0x0)       = 0 0
1636/0x1654e:  close_nocancel(0x0)       = 0 0
1636/0x1654e:  open_nocancel("/dev/null\0", 0x0, 0x1B6)      = 0 0
1636/0x1654e:  close_nocancel(0x1)       = 0 0
1636/0x1654e:  open_nocancel("/dev/null\0", 0x601, 0x1B6)        = 1 0
1636/0x1654e:  close_nocancel(0x2)       = 0 0
1636/0x1654e:  open_nocancel("/dev/null\0", 0x601, 0x1B6)        = 2 0
1636/0x1654e:  audit_session_self(0x664, 0x7FFF5FBFF228, 0x7FFF82B6B366)         = 2563 0
1635/0x1654c:  sigsuspend(0x0, 0x0, 0x0)         = -1 Err#4
1635/0x1654c:  sigreturn(0x7FFF5FBFEE80, 0x1E, 0x7FFF5FBFEE80)       = 0 Err#-2
1635/0x1654c:  __pthread_canceled(0x0, 0x0, 0x7FFF5FBFEF38)      = -1 Err#22
1635/0x1654c:  setitimer(0x0, 0x7FFF5FBFEF40, 0x7FFF5FBFEF20)        = 0 0
1635/0x1654c:  kill(0x664, 0x0, 0x1)         = 0 0
1635/0x1654c:  sigaction(0xE, 0x7FFF5FBFEF10, 0x7FFF5FBFEF50)        = 0 0
1635/0x1654c:  setitimer(0x0, 0x7FFF5FBFEF40, 0x7FFF5FBFEF20)        = 0 0
1635/0x1654c:  sigprocmask(0x0, 0x0, 0x7FFF5FBFEF4C)         = 0x0 0
```

Comment: Compare the values of the environment variables listed in the “environment” section of the screen manual when in a local terminal and over ssh. When screen hangs, does `Ctrl+a d` provoke any response? Watch the screen process from another terminal: is it consuming CPU time? Also try watching the screen process with `dtruss -p 12345` where 12345 is the process ID (you need to be root).

Comment: I've added answers to those questions above, to allow better formatting.

Comment: Do you have a `.screenrc`? (If you do, try without it.) Now here are a few things to try in the ssh session: `screen bash`; `screen ls`; become root and run `screen`; become root and run `dtruss screen`.

Comment: It was when trying a .screenrc for the first time (to display tabs along the bottom line) that I discovered the problem. Removing the file makes no difference. Trying with a new user account for the first time, that had the same issues. I've captured the output from dtruss for the two cases and they inevitably differ wildly, but from a surprisingly early point. The working case does an lstat64() on a bunch of /dev/{p,t}tytN (N=6,7,8,9,A) and then a stat64(), mkdir(), access() and another stat64() inside my $TMPDIR. There's then reading of terminfo etc. before they converge with an ioctl().

Comment: I've added 'dtruss' output of the failing case to the question. The working case is available if required, but it's 2300 lines long.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are not the only one with this problem. Screen hangs in an Apple-specific bit of code. It seems that [if you take out this bit of code and recompile, it works](http://d4t3n7od.wordpress.com/2010/02/10/snow-leopard%C2%B4s-usrbinscreen-does-not-work-if-logged-in-via-ssh-here-is-how-i-solved-this/).

- You need to have the Apple development tools (Xcode) installed.
- Download the [screen source](http://www.opensource.apple.com/tarballs/screen/screen-16.tar.gz). (There is a more recent version, screen-19, where you'll have to take out the offending code by hand in `screen.c`.) Then unpack it:

  ```
  tar -xzf screen-16.tar.gz
  cd screen-16
  ```
- Take out the first and third chunks of the patch to `screen.c`; that is, `patches/screen.c.diff` should now contain

  ```
  --- screen.c    2003-09-08 07:26:41.000000000 -0700
  +++ screen.c    2009-02-13 12:05:05.000000000 -0800
  @@ -929,6 +934,16 @@
      Panic(0, "No $SCREENDIR with multi screens, please.");
   #endif
       }
  +#ifdef __APPLE__
  +    else if (!multi && real_uid == eff_uid) {
  +      static char DarwinSockDir[PATH_MAX];
  +      if (confstr(_CS_DARWIN_USER_TEMP_DIR, DarwinSockDir, sizeof(DarwinSockDir))) {
  +   strlcat(DarwinSockDir, ".screen", sizeof(DarwinSockDir));
  +   SockDir = DarwinSockDir;
  +      }
  +    }
  +#endif /* __APPLE__ */
  +
   #ifdef MULTIUSER
     if (multiattach)
       {
  ```
- Now compile the code:

  ```
  make install_source
  make
  ```
- Check that the resulting executable `/tmp/screen/Build/screen` works.
- See [D4T3N7OD's blog](http://d4t3n7od.wordpress.com/2010/02/10/snow-leopard%C2%B4s-usrbinscreen-does-not-work-if-logged-in-via-ssh-here-is-how-i-solved-this/) for how to replace the official screen executable by yours.

---

I have no idea why screen hangs, why the fix above works, and what you lose by removing this bit of patch. In case anyone is interested, here's how far I went tracing down the code.

- Screen forks a child process, which freezes after opening `/dev/null` on std{in,out,err} and calling `audit_session_self`. The corresponding place in the source is in [`screen.c`](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/screen/screen-19/screen/screen.c), where we see a call to a private Apple API:

  ```
  #if defined(__APPLE__) && !TARGET_OS_EMBEDDED
      if (_vprocmgr_detach_from_console(0) != NULL)
          errx(1, "can't detach from console");
  #endif
  ```
- This code seems to originate from the [Apple patch for screen 11](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/screen/screen-11/patches/screen.c.diff).
- The implementation of `_vprocmgr_detach_from_console` seems to be in [`libvproc`](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/launchd/launchd-329.3.1/launchd/src/libvproc.c), where it leads to

  ```
  task_name_for_pid(mach_task_self(), getpid(), &tnp);
  vproc_mig_switch_to_session(bootstrap_port, tnp, (char *)target_session, _audit_session_self(), &new_bsport))
  ```

  Here we recognize `_audit_session_self`, the last (Darwin) system call that worked.
- Next up is the Mach call [`switch_to_session`](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/launchd/launchd-329.3.1/launchd/src/protocol_vproc.defs?txt). This is where I lose track.

Comment: That sounds very promising, but it might be a day or two before I get chance to sit down and go through the process. Ideally 10.6.5 (due any day now?) will fix it properly, so I may wait to see if that makes a difference. Or am I being too optimistic? Anyway, thanks for chasing this one.

Comment: This problem has happened again in 10.12.6 (was working fine in 10.11.6), it also breaks nohup which calls the same vproc_detach_from_console

Answer (score 1):

This is in macOS 10.12.6 (it was working fine in 10.11.6 without the change below)

If you're logging in via ssh and nohup is failing at the same system call with ioctl and undefined errors and screen is hanging as described above, enable UsePAM in /etc/ssh/sshd_config. We found that doing a su - $USER and then running screen or nohup would work from inside SSH, but straight login via ssh and then running the commands would not (unless UsePAM was enabled). There must be some added "security" features/hooks that is causing this to have to be enabled.